# add foo to all of the fprintf()

Tags: c, file, file-io

I have a code which is written in the C programming language. In this code I have more than 200 lines with this command `fprintf(stdout,"--- This is just fo foo! ---\n");` . I want to add something like *hello foo* at the beginning of the output. In this case the result will be like this :

**hello foo--- This is just fo foo! ---**. 
But the point is the lines are more than 200 and I refuse to add *hello foo* to all 200 lines. So is there any C function or anything to do that for me?

Comment: Don't you have an editor with search-replace functionality?

Comment: yes I have. But my problem is another thing which make me to looking for the answer of this question .

Comment: You could do this with a string-prepending macro, but only if it's for a short-term, ad-hoc solution

Comment: Are all your `fprintf` calls different? Either with the text being printed, or even having different formatting codes?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yes they call different. For example one is "--- This is just fo foo! ---" another one is "I like football!!!". that way I have difficulties with search-replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this opportunity to do a global search-and-replace on your whole codebase, and change each line to:

```
fo_foo();
```

and add in a common header:

```
inline void fo_foo() { fprintf(stdout, "hello foo--- etc."); }
```

Next time you need to change this string you will only have to do it in one place.

Answer (score 2):

You could solve it by making a new function that takes the text you really want to print, and the new function uses `printf` to print the wanted text with the prefix:

```
void my_print(const char *text)
{
    printf("hello foo--- %s", text);
}
```

Then query-replace all calls to use the new function instead.

Answer (score 1):

type following command on vi/vim editor

:%s/--- /hello \foo---/g in esc mode.

it will replace the occurrence of <--- > to < hello foo--- >